# How do I boot into the EFI firmware shell?

Tags: startup, efi

I'd like to experiment with the EFI shell on a MacBook Pro 2010 model.  I am unable to find the keyboard sequence to hold on boot.  Does someone know what the sequence is, do I need to boot from my Snow Leopard CD instead to access this or has the EFI shell been left out (I read that Intel makes it an optional component) ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, apparently it is missing and you have to install [EDK](http://www.intel.com/technology/efi/main_sample.htm) to get it.